# Laravel Nova multiple image

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-nova

I have a nova resource named Product.
I want to associate several images to this product in order to show a gallery image in the front end.
How can I associate multiple images to this product?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you should create the relation between your gallery and the product. Through this solution you can fetch the different Image collections and render them on page.